# Getting values from one aspx page to other

Tags: asp.net

Hi
I have two aspx pages page1.aspx and page2.aspx. I have an InsertButton on page1. when I click Insert,I am opening page2.aspx using javasript( window.open). Now, in page2, i am giving some input in textboxes. when click on OK button on page2,that page has to be closed and I have to use those inputs in page1. How can I do this..

Could some one help me pls??
(I tried using session. But It didn't wrk for me.)

thanks,

Comment: this is the case where sessions can be used in a very good manner.so what problem are u facing using sessions?

Answer (score 0):

try storing the values in page2.aspx in session variables.it will definitely work

Answer (score 0):

its so simple....first you must bring that specified value to a session

like,,,,
session["PID"]=text1.text.ToString();

after that you must declare a public string/int/any variable on the another page(where u want to get the session value)

then pass the session["PID"] to the publically declared variable(public string VARNAME)

like,,,,,,
VARNAME=Session["PID"].Tostring();